# Not able to find Analytics option in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I've `Elasticsearch and Kibana 7.10.0` installed on `Centos7.9` which is working fine but I am not able see `Analytics` option as per below screenshot.
[image]

whereas my current `Kibana Dashboard` look like this -

[image]

Any suggestion here how should I get this `Analytics` option.

Answer (score 0):

You are refering screenshot of latest version in which they have changed header name from `Kibana` to `Analytics` and in 7.10 header name is `Kibana` but in both screenshot you can see same inner heading like Discover, Dashboard etc.

It is just UI design change of Kibana.

I will suggest to install Elasticsearch version 7.17 or ltest version 8.1.